# Date Arithmetic in Excel

Tags: excel

I have some dates in column A of an Excel Spreadsheet and I have some Events in column B.

```
DATE            EVENT
1/23/2012 5:22  a
1/23/2012 5:22  b
1/23/2012 5:22  c
1/24/2012 8:48  d
1/24/2012 9:22  e
1/24/2012 9:25  f
```

I would like column C to be the difference in time (in minutes) since the last event. I tried a `=SUM(A3-A2)`, for example, but it returns a decimal that I can't make sense of (0.023912037, 0.001875, 0.016747685, etc).

I'm not proficient in excel at all so even a point in the right direction would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: More useful info can be found at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datearith.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it correctly.

Excel stores and calculates time as a decimal portion of a day.  24 hours = 1. 12 hours equal 0.5

Format your cell as time (select, right click, format cells, choose one of the time formats) or wrap your formula in `=TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss")`.

Also there's no need to use `=SUM()`,  Your final formula should just be `=A3-A2` or if you need the text formatting `=TEXT(A3-A2,"hh:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 2):

As @Jesse says, your resulting decimal value is in Days.  If you want to convert your value to Minutes, instead of formatting to display as time, just multiply by # of hours and minutes in a day.

```
=(A3-A2)*24*60
```

Comment: To get the difference in minutes it's also possible to use just =A3-A2 and custom format result cell as [m]....but note that for calculation purposes the underlying value is still that decimal...

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot about using brakets in the format. When I played with formatting earlier I couldn't get minutes to show without also showing hours or seconds. Otherwise Excel thought I wanted to see the month.